# WCF service hosted in IIS throws 'Failed to access IIS metabase' error

Tags: wcf

Deployed a WCF service in IIS 6.0 gave NETWORK_sERVICE user read/write privileges.
When tries to brows to .SVC file i get below error

```
Failed to access IIS metabase. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentException: Failed to access IIS metabase. 

The process account used to run ASP.NET must have read access to the IIS metabase (e.g. IIS://servername/W3SVC). For information on modifying metabase permissions, please see http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=267904.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[HostingEnvironmentException: Failed to access IIS metabase.]
   System.Web.Configuration.MetabaseServerConfig.MapPathCaching(String siteID, VirtualPath path) +637
   System.Web.Configuration.MetabaseServerConfig.System.Web.Configuration.IConfigMapPath2.MapPath(String siteID, VirtualPath vpath) +9
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPathActual(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean permitNull) +174
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPathInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean permitNull) +51
   System.Web.CachedPathData.GetConfigPathData(String configPath) +341
   System.Web.CachedPathData.GetConfigPathData(String configPath) +234
   System.Web.CachedPathData.GetApplicationPathData() +38
   System.Web.CachedPathData.GetVirtualPathData(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean permitPathsOutsideApp) +8806383
   System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.GetLKGRuntimeConfig(VirtualPath path) +117
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was told that we get 'Failed to access IIS metabase' error if we install IIS after intalling .NET Framework, and remedy is to re-install ASP.NET.

To resolve this error I have followed below steps
1. Stopped IIS
2. Ran below command in command prompt to re-install aspnet.

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

Result:
Start installing ASP.NET (2.0.50727).
..................................................................
Finished installing ASP.NET (2.0.50727).
3. Re-started IIS and WCF service is responding without any issues.

Comment: If you want to add something to your post, you should **update** your question by **editing** it - don't post "dummy answers" to provide more info.....

Comment: @marc_s is right, but this dummy answer solved my problem, so +1.